# Error " syntax error, unexpected 'preg_match' (T_STRING) in"

Tags: php

I keep getting this error message saying:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'preg_match' (T_STRING) in
```

In this line:

```
Public function isDataValid()
{
return (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9](5-12)$/',$this->_username) (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9](8-12)$/',$this->_password)))? 1 = 0;
```

Can't figure this out. Help

Comment: What are you trying to do? The code you've got doesn't make a lot of sense, syntactically speaking.

Comment: @duskwuff, this a login form and this code is to validate inputs..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is about second `preg_match` because you have missing `&&` OR `||` between those conditions.
And also wrong `=` must be `:` if you use one line statement of `if` like below.

```
(condition) ? "here_what_if_the_condition_is_true" : "and_here_if_it_is_wrong" ;
```

look:

```
return (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9](5-12)$/',$this->_username) (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9](8-12)$/',$this->_password)))? 1 = 0;
```

And correct one is:

```
return (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9](5-12)$/',$this->_username) && (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9](8-12)$/',$this->_password))) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: thank I did the same.. return (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9](5-12)$/',$this->_username) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9](8-12)$/',$this->_password))? 1 = 0;
Now it says "syntax error, unexpected '=' in"

Comment: I said, change = to : , in inline condition u cannot use = inline condition explained is: ( condition ) ? trueValue : falseValue; Where ? represents if condition is true and : if false.

Comment: thanks @kamil.. it wwas my mistake.. It worked.. got new error error though in different section..